# How to prevent RenderBox from drawing over other widgets?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

[image]

If I have a `RenderBox` (in the form of a [`LeafRenderObjectWidget`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/LeafRenderObjectWidget-class.html)) anywhere on the screen, it will always get called with a `PaintingContext` that starts at `Offset(0.0, 0.0)`. This can be fixed by translating the `Canvas` or using a [`RenderShiftedBox`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/RenderShiftedBox-class.html) for convenience.

[image]

Now, the `RenderBox` will paint from its *actual position*. This works fine for me, however, I want to restrict my `RenderBox` from drawing over other widgets even if the canvas operation happens outside of these bounds.

[image]

How do I approach this? I thought about clipping the `LeafRenderObjectWidget`, but I have no idea where the area of my `RenderBox` will start.

If it was not clear before, I have everything I need to determine where the `RenderBox` starts and ends. I get the upper position from the `Offset` that is provided as a parameter in `paint` and I have the size because I set it in `performResize`, but I do not know how to clip using this because that information is inside of the `RenderBox`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few possibilities:

- Wrap your `RenderBox` into a `ClipRect`. Easy but a bit cheating
- use `PaintingContext.pushClipRect` inside the `paint` function of your `RenderBox`

The following clip a painting to not overflow `RenderBox`

```
@override
void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
  context.pushClipRect(
      needsCompositing, offset, Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height),
      (context, offset) {
    // TODO: do some painting
  });
}
```

Comment: Depends. They don't exactly do the same thing. `pushX` methods splits the rendering into independent steps. `canvas.x` don't

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the accepted answer, wrapping your RenderBox with a ClipRect works great! It's so simple that I overlooked it. This is what the code looks like

```
Container(
          /*Code for container*/
          child: ClipRect(
           child: CustomPaint(
             painter: MyPainter(),
             size: Size.infinite,
           ), 
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: You are the life saver